# How to globally update font-size based on user selection?

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, font-size

I want the users to have the option to select the font-size of the overall application i.e have three options: Big, Medium, Small. 
If a user selects "Big", then the overall font-sizes of the application are resized accordingly, globally. I have researched on this issue for quite some time but have not been able to find a solution to globally resize  **all** the fonts (for example when "Big" is selected, all of the fonts would get x-times bigger)

Answer (score 0):

You should set `font-size` for `html` tag, then, for other selectors use `font-size` with *rem* or *em*. I prefer *rem*. *rem* is calculated based on `html` font-size.
After that, you can change `html` font-size by adding classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to accomplish this is to set a pixel based font size on the body element and use the em unit for other elements so that their font sizes will be relative to the one of the body element.

Then you add your buttons and let them change the font size of the body element via JavaScript when someone clicks on them. The font sizes of the elements using em values will change accordingly

Answer (score -1):

You could try the following:

CSS

```
:root {
  --font-size: 20px;
}
div {
  font-size: var(--font-size);
}
```

JS

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--font-size', '16px');
```

---

Setting the font size on the html element and then referencing it with em would also work:

```
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}
html.big {
  font-size: 20px;
}
div {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```